# Is there a prettier way to get an integer inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Normally, the way to accept an integer input from the user is given by:

```
x = int(input('Enter a value: '))
```

But in my opinion, this casting of a string to an integer is somewhat ugly. Is there a direct and perhaps prettier way to do this?
(Of course I know I could just make my own 'pretty' function; perhaps there's a way that's built into the language?).

Comment: There isn't. Why do you consider it ugly? If you're parsing command line arguments, you can specify `type=int` and have `argparse` do it for you.

Comment: I'm unsure about this but I believe you need the `int` conversion only in python2, or in python3 if you use `raw_input`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @asfeynman: What is your definition of beautiful?

Comment: @JulienBernu: In Python 2, `input()` is `eval(raw_input())`. In Python 3, `input()` is `raw_input()` from Python 2.

Comment: the user is inputting characters. You do have to convert that at some point.

Comment: @SivNiz I suppose it's something that doesn't casts?.. I'm beginning to realize this question is bit stupid now hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def pretty_input(prompt):
  return int(input(prompt))

x = pretty_input("Enter a value: ")
```

Comment: "Of course I know I could just make my own 'pretty' function; perhaps there's a way that's built into the language?"

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist. 
input() will always return a string in Python 3. There aren't really any alternatives.

Comment: I suppose this question is pretty stupid, so this answer is appropriate :)